# Bounty Tags should be ordered by value

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I look on the active tag, and find bounty tags. I find tags that are worth +50 above tags worth +100.

I think they should be ordered based on their numericality.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what exactly you're seeing? The answer will vary depending on where exactly you are, but it's a little unclear to me from your description what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this what you're looking for, by any chance?

[image: bounty size]

Comment: Thanks! I never noticed that before